# Is there a way to reset the toolbar minigraphs in Process Explorer?

Tags: windows, process-explorer, sysinternals

Windows Sysinternals Process Explorer includes in its toolbar some **minigraphs** showing recent usage history for CPU, Memory, and so on:

[image: Process Explorer toolbar minigraphs]

These are nice. However, an inadvertent click on the 'thumb' of one of these will cause it to maximize within the toolbar, and hide all the others:

[image: Oops]

Is there an easy way to reset all the minigraphs to equal width? A hard way that works is to painstakingly manually drag all the thumbs where you want them, being sure not to simply *click* a thumb, which puts you back where you started.

I found [this post from April 2012 on a Process Explorer Feature Requests forum](http://forum.sysinternals.com/feature-requests_topic7272_post134717.html#134717), but I can't find anything more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Exit Process Explorer completely (using *File* | *Exit*, or right-click a tray icon and choose *Close Process Explorer*)
2. Using `regedit`, go to

   ```
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sysinternals\Process Explorer
   ```

and delete the key `ToolbarBands`

1. Restart Process Explorer.

Source: [ProcessExplorer settings](https://web.archive.org/web/20141015220027/http://forum.sysinternals.com/faq-common-processexplorer-issues_topic15922.html).

Comment: For anyone who wishes to run it in PowerShell or script it: `Remove-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Sysinternals\Process Explorer\' -Name 'ToolbarBands'`